# How do I destructure a promise returned by axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, axios, react-hooks

Below is the code to fetch some data

```
    useEffect(async (id) => {
//    const data = await redditFetch(id);
async function redditFetch(id){
    try {
        const {data:{data}} = await axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=${id}&limit=50`);
        const {children} = data;
        return children.map(data=> data.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
const data = redditFetch(id);
setData(data)
},[setData])

console.log(Data);
```

And this is the promise returned:

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(50)
```

What I want is the Array inside the PromiseResult.

I've also tried another away using async await like this which returns a proper array.

```
const PostPage = () => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    const [Data, setData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(async (id) => {
    //    const data = await redditFetch(id);
    async function redditFetch(id){
        try {
            const {data:{data}} = await axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=${id}&limit=50`);
            const {children} = data;
            return children.map(data=> data.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    const data = await redditFetch(id);
    setData(data)
    },[setData])

    console.log(Data);
```

But with this comes a bloody warning that I can't get rid of:

> index.js:1 Warning: An effect function must not return anything
> besides a function, which is used for clean-up.
>
> It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a
> Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call
> it immediately:
>
> useEffect(() => {   async function fetchData() {
> // You can await here
> const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
> // ...   }   fetchData(); }, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state

So, my dear coders, tell me what to do???

Comment: The warning message tells you what to do. It even has example code.

Comment: I've tried that as well but as I said, I get that promise....which sadly I don't know how to desructure. Which is why I'm here

Comment: Broadly speaking, I could've ignored the warning, but Surge and GitHub actions treat warning as error and won't accept my code while the warning exists

Comment: The warning says that you should use `useEffect(() => { async function ...`  and you have `useEffect(async () => { async function ...` Can you spot the difference?

Comment: The async in the front of the useEffect..now i've removed that.. now i have this:

Comment: Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: Array(50)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anything return from useEffect supposed to be clean up while component unmount. Better you may invoke setData function there instead of return.

On the other hand,  you may use  immediate invoke function (IIF) then you do not need to resolve the promise that return from redditFetch function.

Answer (score 0):

I did a sample demo with the post code:

##### CODESANDBOX: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-nobel-p87mt9?file=/src/App.js:257-265

- In your code `const data = redditFetch(id);` the `async` functions will return a `Promise`. You have to use `await`, but React will warn you to not transform the `useEffect` callback in `async` function
- You can remove the API function of your `useEffect`.
- Don't put the `setDate` in your `useEffect` dependency array. In this case, you can leave this empty to run just one time. Also, don't put the `date` because will re-render in an infinite loop. If you need some conditional just remove the dependency array and put some conditional to run `setDate`.

> I had to mock the `id` in the query parameter to be possible to work with API

**CODE:**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

async function redditFetch() {
  try {
    const {
      data: { data }
    } = await axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=01&limit=50`);
    const { children } = data;
    return children.map((data) => data.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const Data = data.map((redditContent) => {
    return (
      <div key={redditContent.name}>
        <h2>{redditContent.title}</h2>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const redditResponse = await redditFetch();
      console.log(redditResponse);
      setData(redditResponse);
    })();
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">{Data}</div>;
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE: CLEANER APPROACH (No anonymous function)**

> If you don't like of anonymous function approach, you can use this one:

```js
  async function updateRedditPosts() {
    const redditResponse = await redditFetch();
    console.log(redditResponse);
    setData(redditResponse);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    updateRedditPosts();
  }, []);
```